# remove all git tags cross-platform

Tags: git

I'm trying to remove all local and remote git tags
I found several methods to accomplish this, but none of them works natively for cross-platforms

for example: in windows

`git tag -d $(git tag -l)` causes the error:

```
`switch `l' : incompatible with --delete`
```

`git tag -l | xargs git tag -d` causes `'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

this worked in windows but fails in linux `for /f "tokens=* delims=" %a in ('git tag -l') do git tag -d %a`

I'm looking for a command to delete all git tags (locally and remotely) in cross-platform

Comment: Are typing the command into CMD on Windows? That is not a POSIX shell, hence, you cannot use the `$(...)` syntax and expect it to work like in a POSIX shell.

Comment: that what I ask for, I need a cross-platform command that runs natively on both windows and POSIX

Comment: Then use a shell that's available on both. Bash or powershell for exemple.

Comment: Use a POSIX-compatible shell, such as bash; Git always comes with one if the platform does not provide one already.

Comment: You can use cross-platform tools, but at some point you have to pick a specific one and use that.